# Display (and play) just a section of a video?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am using [Video.js](https://videojs.com/city) with a `WebVTT` file for chapters and subtitles; that is working fine. For another feature in the app I am developing, in place of using chapters, I am wondering if there is a way I can display and play just a section of a video? For example, "Cue F" in the test file screenshot shown below is 16 seconds long – is there a way I can show the video as just having 16 seconds duration instead of having to show it in the context of the entire video duration? (This would mean the Control Bar reflected the 16 second length, etc)

Said another way, I want to be able to show "clips" of a video to the user without them being able to jump around by clicking the 'seek' bar, etc.

I've been through the Video.js docs and all the listed plugins but haven't seen a way to do this. I am comfortable writing the code – but I'm not sure where to start – Video.js doesn't seem to support [Media Fragments](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-video-fragments-captions-dynamic-thumbnails/) (or at least threw errors when I tried it)

[image]

Comment: Are you able to use current time property?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime.  We recently had a project where we needed similar functionality with our media.  I'm not familiar with video.js, but if you can simply reach into the video element and set the position, it should be fairly simple.

Comment: @Zbow - thanks for the comment. Video.js (a wrapper for HTML5 video) has a `currentTime` property and I can set that – but it doesn't expose any props to set a playback range which the UI will treat as the overall duration. I've been looking at the `videojs-offset `plugin and it looks like they override some of the methods to get the result I want. I guess I could also do custom controls too.